# Django ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have done this in my base template:

```
            {% if user.profile.image %}
              <img class="user-image" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}/" alt="User profile picture">
            {% else %}
                <img class="user-image" src="{% static 'userprofile/download (1).jpg' %}">
            {% endif %}
```

And in profile details page have done this:

```
            {% if profile_details.image %}
              <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ profile_details.image.url }}/" alt="User profile picture">
            {% else %}
                <img class="profile-user-img  img-circle" src="{% static 'userprofile/download (1).jpg' %}">
            {% endif %}
```

And in my models I have done this:

```
 from PIL import Image
 from io import BytesIO
 from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
 import sys

 class Profile(models.Model):
      Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      Full_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
      Name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      E_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images', null=True, blank=True)

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          imageTemproary = Image.open(self.image)
          outputIoStream = BytesIO()
          imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize( (128,128) ) 
          imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream , format='JPEG', quality=150)
          outputIoStream.seek(0)
          self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream,'ImageField', "%s.jpg" %self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
          super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is coming in this line of code:

```
 imageTemproary = Image.open(self.image)
```

Traceback:

```
 Traceback:

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
     35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
    128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
     126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
    69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
   89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
   172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
   142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  125.         self.object = form.save()

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in save
  120.             user.save()

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in save
  73.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
 729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
 769.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

  File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

  File "C:\Users\HP\My Documents\github\erpcloud\erpcloud\userprofile\models.py" in user_created
   82.      Profile.objects.create(Name=instance)

 File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
 417.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\HP\My Documents\github\erpcloud\erpcloud\userprofile\models.py" in save
 68.        imageTemproary = Image.open(self.image)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py" in open
2584.         fp.seek(0)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\utils.py" in <lambda>
 20.     seek = property(lambda self: self.file.seek)

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in _get_file
 41.         self._require_file()

File "C:\Users\HP\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in _require_file
 38.             raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

 Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/signup/
 Exception Value: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Can anyone explain me what is wrong in my code

Comment: What if `self.image == None`?

Comment: Can you update with a traceback at least or the error you are getting?

Comment: self.image should be the path to your image, maybe it does not exist? It would be easier if you posted the error message

Comment: Yeah I have updated my post

Comment: I think this error makes a lot of sense to me. You are trying to open `self.image` in a `save` method where most probably you have `self.image` empty. Another thing that `self.image` is an object of image not a path since it is not a `PathField`. Would you mind print `self.image` and see what the value it has, it will explain a lot.

Comment: Its not printing anything...

Comment: which means that this `self.image` is really empty. You can be extra sure that prefixing the print with any character. Something like `print("Value: " + self.image)`.
To be able to help you, I'd ask you to post the function calling this save.